# Is it possible to make Kendo UI DataViz to Display Radial Gauge in Half instead of full circle

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I'm trying to create a radial gauge with Kendo UI. I notice on the demo, it render radial gauge as a full circle. Is it possible to have the gauge render only the top half?

I looked at the documentation on http://docs.kendoui.com/api/dataviz/radialgauge. Looks like they allow us to configure the angle of the scales, but I couldn't find one for the actual gauge itself.

Any idea on how to tackle this?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn out the frame for the radial is simply a background graphic.

Just change the CSS to the target image file to customize the graphic for radial gauge.

```
#gauge-container {
    background: transparent url("../../content/dataviz/gauge/gauge-container.png") no-repeat 50% 50%;
    width: 404px;
    height: 404px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 0 30px 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set `startAngle :0` and `endAngle :180` and full circle is background image.